# Adding decode in Case statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to check the condition

```
case 
    when (travel_country = sr.country_id and state_expense_purpose_desc = 1) 
         or (travel_country is null and state_expense_purpose_desc = 1) 
        then '1' 
        else '0' 
end) thrd_prty_domestic
```

and also add a condition that if the `thrd_prty_domestic = 1`, then show the amount column as `rt.amount`.

I tried to add decode function in the case statement like below

```
(case 
     when ((travel_country = sr.country_id and state_expense_purpose_desc = 1) 
           or (travel_country is null and state_expense_purpose_desc = 1)) a 
         then decode(a, rt.amount, 0) 
         else null 
 end) thrd_prty_domestic
```

but it did not work.

Please help on how can I check the 2 conditions and if the result is yes then show the amount for that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - please update your question with table definitions, sample data, the result you want to achieve and a complete SQL statement that you’ve managed to write

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `DECODE`, just put `rt.amount` into the `THEN` clause of your `CASE` expression:

```sql
CASE
WHEN (travel_country = sr.country_id OR travel_country is null)
AND  state_expense_purpose_desc = 1
THEN rt.amount
ELSE 0
END AS amount
```

Answer (score 2):

Why `decode`? `case` is easier to understand.

Check your current `case` expression and - if it is `'1'`, return `rt.amount`.

```
select
case when 
        -- beginning of your current CASE expression
        case when     (travel_country = sr.country_id and state_expense_purpose_desc = 1) 
                   or (travel_country is null         and state_expense_purpose_desc = 1) 
             then '1' 
             else '0' 
        end 
        -- end of your current CASE expression
        = 1 then rt.amount
else null
end thrd_prty_domestic
from rt join sr on ...   --> it is unclear how tables are related to each other
```